# is there a problem with my code that prevents the VK_UP event from happening?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So I've been writing a function that sets the text in the hEdit to "Oops it's up" when the key UP is pressed, but it doesn't work at all. Like when I press this key, nothing happens, I even tried to use the a MessageBox() function instead of SetWindowtextW(), but it still doesn't do a thing. Can smn help me identify the issue?

```
 case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
      switch(wp)
     {
      case VK_UP:
      
        SetWindowTextW(hEdit, L"Oops it's up");
      
    break;
    }
break;
}
```

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define VK_UP    0x26



using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void AddControls(HWND hWnd);

HWND hEdit;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"my Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 500, 500,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    static bool timerActive = false;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case VK_UP:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"key up", L"", MB_OK);
            break;
        }

        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        if (!timerActive)
        {
            wchar_t user_input[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, user_input, 100);

            POINT mousePos;
            GetCursorPos(&mousePos);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &mousePos);

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            TextOutW(hdc, mousePos.x, mousePos.y, user_input, wcslen(user_input));
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

            // Set a timer to erase the text after 500 milliseconds
            SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 400, NULL);
            timerActive = true;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        if (!timerActive)
        {
            wchar_t user_reverse_input[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, user_reverse_input, 100);
            reverse(user_reverse_input, user_reverse_input + wcslen(user_reverse_input));

            POINT mousePos;
            GetCursorPos(&mousePos);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &mousePos);

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            TextOutW(hdc, mousePos.x, mousePos.y, user_reverse_input, wcslen(user_reverse_input));
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

            // Set a timer to erase the reversed text after 500 milliseconds
            SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 400, NULL);
            break;
        }
    }

    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if (wp == 1)
        {
            KillTimer(hWnd, 1);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            timerActive = false;
        }
        break;
    }



    case WM_CREATE:
        AddControls(hWnd);
        SetFocus(hEdit);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }

    return 0;
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    HWND hStatic = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Enter text here:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 10, 220, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (hStatic == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Static control creation failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }

    hEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 10, 45, 170, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (hEdit == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Edit control creation failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that the problem is that your main window does not have the focus so it does not recieve any key events at all. Presumably one of your edit controls has the focus.

Comment: It is used by the Edit control to move the caret.  If you want to see it as well then you'll have to [subclass the control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).  With the side-effect that you can't move the caret with the keyboard anymore, maybe better if you don't do that.

Comment: Don't tag with C the C+ code.

Comment: Thank you, but i do not quite understand what do u mean by handling it bc i thought it is handled in the case WM_KEYUP

Comment: See [Keyboard Input Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input) for a description of how keyboard input moves through the system.

Comment: Please don't accept an answer that doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: And please don't edit your answer into the question. The [tour] will explain how this site is intended to work.

Comment: @tetiana.mlk You are handling `VK_UP` in the parent window's `WndProc`, but when the Edit control has input focus then `VK_UP` (and other input messages) will not go to the parent window, it will go to the Edit's `WndProc` instead, that is why you would need to [subclass the Edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) to handle its input messages.

Comment: @tetiana.mlk On a side note: you are using `TextOutW` incorrectly. You should not draw on a window outside of its `WM_PAINT` handler (to see why, move another window on top of your app's window, and then move it away, before your timer elapses. Your text will disappear prematurely). You need to store your desired text in a string variable and then draw that variable on the window in reply to `WM_PAINT`. You can use the timer to change the text of that string and invalidate the window to trigger a repaint.

Comment: A [Windows hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) might help with this.  Happy exploring!

Comment: `SetWindowTextW` [works fine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-a-multiline-edit-control). But `WM_KEYDOWN` is not sent your window but the Editor control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [`WM_SETCURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor) is the only received message to the parent window when moving the cursor in the editor control. My answer is based on the fact and attempt to show a simple solution.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    ...
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
    {
        SHORT s = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP);
        if (s&0x8000)
        {
            SetWindowTextW(hEdit, L"Oops it's up");
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    ...
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
    {
        ...
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_SETCURSOR:
        {
            SHORT s = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP);
            if (s&0x8000)
            {
                SetWindowTextW(hEdit, L"Oops it's up");
            }
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
        }
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer indeed helped me to neutrilize the issue, but instead i do not see the cursor moving on the window anymore

Comment: @tetiana.mlk, I have updated my answer. According to [WM_SETCURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor), *The `DefWindowProc` function also uses this message to set the cursor to an arrow if it is not in the client area, or to the registered class cursor if it is in the client area.*

Comment: This works perfectly) Thank you for your help!